# Connection state is closed error when connection is open

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the following error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Yet, in my code, the connection state is opened right before this exception is thrown. I don't understand why it says it would be closed??

Code:

```
Try

conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

If i = objId.Count - 1 Then
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Update DmdOD SET note = @note, note1 = @note1, noteBranch = @branch, noteAccountNo = @account," & _
    "noteType = @type, noteSub = @sub, lastUpdatedBy = @user  WHERE no = @no and id=@id", conn)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", objId.Item(i)))
End If

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@note", ddl.SelectedItem.Text))

If ddlNote.SelectedItem.Text IsNot "" Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@note1", ddlNote.SelectedItem.Text))
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@note1", DBNull.Value))
End If


If txtAccountBox.Text IsNot "" Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@account", txtAccountBox.Text))
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@account", DBNull.Value))
End If

If txtSubBox.Text IsNot "" Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sub", txtSubBox.Text))
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sub", DBNull.Value))
End If

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@no", row.Cells(1).Text))

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@user", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()))

If ddBranchBox.SelectedItem.Text IsNot "" Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@branch", ddBranchBox.SelectedItem.Text))
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@branch", DBNull.Value))
End If

If ddTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text IsNot "" Then
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@type", ddTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text))
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@type", DBNull.Value))
End If

conn.Open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' Where the exception is being thrown
conn.Close()

   cmd.Parameters.Clear()

   LblErr.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
   LblErr.Text = "Data Saved!"

Catch ex As Exception
   LblErr.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkRed
   LblErr.Text = "Save Button - " & ex.Message
Finally
   conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created two times the connection. When you build the SqlCommand you associate that command with the connection created just before, but then you recreate again the connection and this new object is no more the same associated with the command-

After adding the parameters remove this line

```
  conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

However you should always enclose disposable objects like a connection with a using block

```
Try

  Using conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
     .....
     create the command
     create the parameters
     ....
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

  End Using  ' Here the connection will be closed and disposed
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

As a side note, what happen in your code if

If i <> objId.Count - 1 Then

Comment: I'll edit my code to reflect there being only one conn, it still does the exception with only the one in there

Comment: I'm using conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString) a few times throughout the program, could this be why I'm seeing that exception?

Comment: Yes if conn is a global object, you should never keep a connection as a global object. There is no much to gain

Comment: If i<> objId.Count -1 Then, I have an arraylist called objId that has a bunch of member id's from the database, the i is something I increment at the end of my for each statement (which is where this code is from)

Comment: However after your fix this answer has no more sense. Are you still experiencing the same error or something has changed?

Comment: Oooooh, no I'm not stepping into the if i=objId.count if statement, that could very well be the issue.

Comment: yup, looks like that was the problem, I commented out the if statement, it stepped into the update and performed the ExecuteNonQuery() without a problem after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your overwrite your instance "conn"

At the beginning of your code you declare "conn"

```
conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

And before open the connection you do that again..
Remove the second assignment.

Comment: I put in the 2nd one because I was trying things out, it still does the exception with only the one in there.

Comment: can you tell me the state after calling "conn.Open()" by investing "conn.State" propertyvalue - btw: i would prefer to avail of "using" statement like @Steve wrote

Comment: state = conn.State Where state is a string, state is equal to 1. Indicating the conn is open

Comment: are you sure you step into: "If i = objId.Count - 1 Then" - because the connection object isnt maybe the same - try to use cmd.Connection.Open() - to access the cmd's Connection instance